# сохранение картинки с добавленным тексом в tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, pillow

Есть небольшая программка, где в изображение добавляется текст, через специальные поля ввода. Интересует как сохранить новую картинку с текстом, при помощи кнопки "сохранить картинку", пробовал через image.save("primer1.jpg") он не сохраняет, очень прошу помощи? И еще интересует, как ограничить в поле ввода, где "добавить год" количество вводимых символов до 4 максимум?

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from tkinter.ttk import Button, Entry
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("Эмблема")
root.geometry("550x550")

def draw_years():
   text = entr1.get()
   canvas.create_text(205, 210, text=text, fill="white", font="Arial 25")

def draw_word():
   text = entr2.get()
   canvas.create_text(205, 250, text=text, fill="white", font="Arial 15")


image = Image.open("primer.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

canvas = Canvas(root, height=400, width=400)
img = canvas.create_image(200, 200, image=photo)
canvas.place(x=30, y=10)

entr1 = Entry(width=10)
entr1.place(x=10, y=430)

btn1 = Button(text="Добавить год", command=draw_years)
btn1.place(x=90, y=430)

entr2 = Entry(width=10)
entr2.place(x=10, y=460)

btn2 = Button(text="Добавить буквы", command=draw_word)
btn2.place(x=90, y=460)

btn3 = Button(text="Выход из приложения", command=root.quit)
btn3.place(x=150, y=500)

# def save_as():

btn4 = Button(text="Сохранить картинку")
btn4.place(x=10, y=500)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886274/how-can-i-convert-canvas-content-to-an-image

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что после root.mainloop(), я прописываю root.update() и после пишу код сохранения и картинка с текстом сохраняется?

Comment: Не после root.mainloop(), а в обработчике нажатия на кнопку "Сохранить картинку"